# Why does this recursive program behave strangely

Tags: python, recursion

I'm writing a simple recursive function that takes a square matrix and the starting position coordinates and the value of the starting position, and then finds if there is a path to the bottom right corner of the square matrix. The rule is to start from the starting position Move right or down, when the value of the next position is less than or equal to the current value, you can move and update the value of the sum of the two, and so on. If it exists, return True and the path, if not, return False and [ ]. Below is the program I wrote

```
def find_path(matrix, x, y, value):
    length = len(matrix)

    if x == y == (length-1):
        return (True,[(x,y)])

    # Go down and search
    if x < length -1 and matrix[x+1][y] <= value:
        hasSolution,solution = find_path(matrix, x+1, y, value + matrix[x+1][y])
        if hasSolution:
            solution.append((x,y))
            return solution
    
    # If the road below is not feasible, take the right
    if y < length -1 and matrix[x][y+1] <= value:
        hasSolution,solution = find_path(matrix, x, y+1, value + matrix[x][y+1])
        if hasSolution:
            solution.append((x,y))
            return solution
    
    # If neither left nor right, it means there is no solution
    return (False,[])
```

However when I enter [[76,13],[40,42]], the python interpreter returns

```
File "/Users/zg/PycharmProjects/z/main.py", line 42, in find_path
     solution.append((x,y))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Why does this result occur?

Comment: Is this the entire code? What 4 parameters are you passing to `find_path`? `solution` is of type `tuple`, needs to be changed to type `list` to make it work - as seen from the error.

Answer (score 0):

From the error it appears that `solution` is a `tuple` and `tuples` are immutable and don't have an `append` method, of course.

`solution` is defined outside of the code snippet you posted so it must be a global variable or in a wrapping function outside of `find_path`. If you want to `append` to it, a `list` would be the right data structure to use.

In addition, `return (True,[(x,y)])` doesn't make much sense since `x` and `y` will always be `length-1` when you find a valid path, so I would reconsider that part of the code.